# How to change a string format like 2d30m to timespan?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, timespan

I dont know what is this format called like `2d30m` in programming language. But, I see some Jquery plugin or Youtube's jump to time url like `&t=3m11s` using this time format. It's hard to google because I dont know the excat keyword.

So, I want to use this kind of format and translated into `TimeSpan` object in C#. How can I achieve this?

Right now I'm trying to extract the value from string by this code

```
public static void Main()
{
    String str = "2d30m";
    int day = 0, minute = 0;
    //Get Day
    day = Helper(str, "d");
    //Get Minute
    minute = Helper(str, "m");
    //Create timespan
    var myTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(days: day, hours: 0, minutes: minute, seconds: 0);
    Console.Write(myTimeSpan);
}

public static int Helper(string input, string timeCode)
{
    int output = 0;
    int indexOf = input.LastIndexOf(timeCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (indexOf > 0)
    {
        string strTime = input.Substring(Math.Max(0, indexOf - 2), 2);
        Console.WriteLine(strTime);
        strTime = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(strTime, "[^0-9.]", ""); // remove all alphabet
        output = Convert.ToInt32(strTime);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TimeSpan.ParseExact`:

```
var str = "2d30m";
// d matches both 1 and 2 digit days
// \d means literal "d"
// m matches both 1 and 2 digit minutes
// \m is literal "m"
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact(str, @"d\dm\m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This is not working if I try to input three digits minutes, i.e "2d120m"

Comment: @vantian yes unfortunately that is limitation of timespan parse methods - it does not accept values that do not match target component range (0-24 for hours, 0-60 for minutes and seconds).

Comment: ah, I see. so it must matches target range for days, minutes, seconds, hours. well, this is acceptable too. but I need to validate the range from user input later on. Both solutions are good, thanks Evk and FrankerZ

Comment: Right, but fortunately days do not have a range (so "4000d30m" is fine). Only hours\minutes\seconds should match their respective range.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Regex.Match` against the entire string. Easy enough to get the groups:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var str = "2d30m";
    //Regex match and find the 2 & 30
    var matches = Regex.Match(@"^(\d+)d(\d+)m$", str);
    //Get Day
    var day = int.Parse(matches.Groups[1].Value);
    //Get Minute
    var minute = int.Parse(matches.Groups[2].Value);
    //Create timespan
    var myTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(days: day, hours: 0, minutes: minute, seconds: 0);
    Console.Write(myTimeSpan);
}
```

See [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/np34zk) here.

Comment: Awesome, it's works. do you mind to explain what regex do in the code?

Comment: @vantian Check the explanation section on the top right [here](https://regex101.com/r/Qi3L9m/1).

Comment: got it, I just know if we can use array groups from regex. learn something new everyday.